# MongoMapper: finding all documents created on a specified date

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I need to write a query that finds all documents created on a specified date.

Let's suppose that the date is today.

I tried this:

```
Document.all(:created_at => Date.parse(Time.now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')))
```

but I got:

> Cannot serialize an object of class Date into BSON.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
This link explains how to do so [Date Range Queries With MongoMapper](https://web.archive.org/web/20130309080838/kplawver.posterous.com/date-range-queries-with-mongomapper).

```
Document.count( :created_at => { '$gt' => 2.days.ago.midnight, '$lt' => 1.day.ago.midnight } )
```

Comment: The link above doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This link explains how to do so [Date Range Queries With MongoMapper](http://kplawver.posterous.com/date-range-queries-with-mongomapper).

```
Document.count( :created_at => { '$gt' => 2.days.ago.midnight, '$lt' => 1.day.ago.midnight } )
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `:created_at` is a Date (as in "JavaScript-style Date with both date and time-of-day components"), right? You'll need to figure out the boundaries of the date in question in UTC, build `Time` instances for those boundaries, and then search for everything between those times.

Assuming that your local time zone is correctly configured and you want everything that was created on 2011-11-21, then something like this should get you there:

```
start_time = Time.new(2011,11,21, 0,0,0).utc
end_time   = Time.new(2011,11,22, 0,0,0).utc
docs       = Document.where(:created_at => { :$gte => start_time }).
                      where(:created_at => { :$lt  => end_time   })
```

You could also use `Time.new(2011, 11, 21).utc` and `Time.new(2011, 11, 22).utc` but I like the extra zeros as a reminder that I'm not really working with just a date.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Time.now` instead. The ruby driver knows how to deal with Time objects.

```
doc = {:created_at => Time.now}
```

or

```
doc = {:created_at => Time.utc(12,1,12)} # year, month, day
```

Then, you can test if the document will serialize without throwing an error in irb like this:

```
require 'bson'

BSON.serialize(doc)
```

If you get an error, try again. If it spits out a serialized bson object, you are good to go!

If you are curious, check out the source of the `to_mongo` method in the mongomapper driver [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/mongomapper/master/MongoMapper/Extensions/Date)

Answer (score 0):

Use the technique @mu-is-to-short pointed out to create the date.

But the format of the where statement can be simpler:

```
date = Time.new(2021,1,24, 0,0,0).utc
docs = Document.where(:updated_at.gte => date).all
```